# Page Fault on Call Instruction

Tags: kernel, xnu

I am trying to boot a custom fork of Apple’s XNU kernel ([sources available here](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel)). The kernel is triple-faulting on [line 325 of start.s](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/x86_64/start.s#L325).

Examining the [QEMU log](https://gist.github.com/wjk/8428182) points to a page fault for the address `0x10BFF8`. This address is one 4K page + 8 bytes before the PML4, which is located at address `0x10D000`. Thing is, though, I do not know why the `call` instruction would page-fault like this. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: It will page fault if there is no page for the virtual address in question, or if the page exists but is not marked present. http://wiki.osdev.org/Paging

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: OK, but **how** is it deriving that virtual address? That’s what’s been stumping me.